# Want to setup pppoe on mikrotik router

Tags: internet, openwrt, pppoe, mikrotik-routeros

I have a Mikrotik RB450G and two TP-Link WR841Nv11 routers.I have OpenWRT installed on both TP-Link routers. The connection from the ISP is given to one TP-Link and its gateway is 172.16.2.1, and I want to set up pppoe for another TP-Link router using Mikrotik from scratch in between them. [image]

Comment: What is your goal exactly? How does the first TP-Link get its IP? How does the MikroTik get its IP? Why do you want the second TP-Link to use PPPoE?

Comment: The main goal is to use radius server, so first only provides internet to mikrotik and second is for to connect radius users.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup PPPOE Service for example on ethernet2

```
/interface pppoe-server server add disabled=no interface=ether2 service-name=pppoe1
```